# Future Builder run again eventhough assigned in InitState

Tags: flutter, dart

> I am using future builder to fetch json data from local json file, everything i expected is working fine, but the problem is when i added a print statement in the future builder i saw in console that the print statement is executing every 2 seconds not stopping
> **

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 @override
 State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
 }

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
//
int activeCarouselIndex = 0;
int _selectedPageIndex = 0;
List _bestEvents = [];
late Future<List<dynamic>> _future;

void _onBottomNavItemTaped(int index) {
if (index != 1)
  setState(() {
    _selectedPageIndex = index;
  });
if (index == 1) {
  Navigator.of(context)
      .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const EventsScreen()));
 }
 }

# assigned the function in initstate

@override
void initState() {
  print("init called");
  super.initState();
 _future = readJson();
}

# function here

Future<List> readJson() async {
final String response =
  await rootBundle.loadString('assets/localAPI/dynamic_images.json');
final data = await json.decode(response);
// print(data);
return data[0]['BestEvents'];
}

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
 final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
 const double _margin = 15.0;
 const double _widgetspace = 25.0;
 return SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: _selectedPageIndex == 2
        ? AppBar(
            toolbarHeight: size.height * 0.09,
            title: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Hi',
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                addVerticalSpace(4),
                Text(
                  'Edit Profile',
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () => print("Profile Account Clicked"),
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                color: COLOR_WHITE,
              ),
            ],
            backgroundColor: COLOR_DARK_BLUE,
          )
         : AppBar(
             toolbarHeight: size.height * 0.09,
            title: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'It All Starts Here',
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                addVerticalSpace(4),
                Text(
                  'Oddanchatram',
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () => print("Search Clicked"),
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                color: COLOR_WHITE,
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () => print("Notify Clicked"),
                icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_outlined),
                color: COLOR_WHITE,
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () => print("QR Clicked"),
                icon: Icon(Icons.qr_code),
                color: COLOR_WHITE,
              ),
            ],
            backgroundColor: COLOR_DARK_BLUE,
          ),
    body: _selectedPageIndex == 2
        ? ProfileScreen()
        : Container(
            width: size.width,
            height: size.height,
            child: Stack(
              fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: [
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                   
                      addVerticalSpace(12.0),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: _margin, right: _margin),
                        child: imageBuilder(context, size),
                      ),
                      
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.live_tv), label: 'Events'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.man), label: 'Profile'),
      ],
      currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
      selectedItemColor: COLOR_PINKISH_RED,
      onTap: _onBottomNavItemTaped,
    ),
  ),
);
 }


**Future Builder Code**


Widget imageBuilder(context, size) {
return FutureBuilder<List>(
    future: _future,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
      print("1"); ## prints multiple times
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        List axeList = snapshot.data!;

        return Container(
          child: GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                  maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                  childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 20),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemCount: axeList.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                            axeList[index]['url'],
                          ),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                );
              }),
        );
      }
      return const Text("No Data");
    });
   }
   }
```

> I saw other questions like these many solved when functions assigned in initstate, anyone know    why its executing many times for me, whether it is harmful to execute like these ??

Comment: Probably you have more than one of `HomeScreen` widget. Every time one of those is inserted in Widget tree you have a print in `initState()`

Comment: init state executed only one time, it prinited "init" only 1 time....

Answer (score 0):

you need to call a query in WidgetsBinding like this

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
_future = readJson();
});
retrieveCalendars();
}
```

Comment: Not working ! says Late initialization error

Comment: can you please send me error string

Comment: hey when i removed all my other widgets and placed only this future builder, the builder only builded for 2 times......but when i added other widgets for my project home page the future builded seems to build many time but calls the future only one time...is this normal ?

Comment: am sorry this is not related to your question but can u clarify me? am like new to flutter